# Load configuration files in asp.net 5 unit tests

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

Currently, I load configurations from configuration files that live in a subdirectory of my unit test project files:

```
        HostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment();
        env.Initialize(@"C:\ProjectRoot\tests\MyProject.Tests", "UnitTesting");
        Startup startup = new Startup(env);

        var cfg = startup.Configuration;
        var cs = cfg.Get("ConnectionStrings:MyApp");
        Assert.NotNull(cs);
```

This looks ugly as it uses the absolution path `C:\ProjectRoot\tests\MyProject.Tests` , which may be vary for other developers.
Is there a way to substitute it with a relative path ?

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` works in both the command line and the visual studio xunit test runner ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` does not work as it returns something along the lines of `C:\\xxxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\bin\\Debug\\net451\\win7-x64` There will not be any config json files here!

Answer (score 0):

You can include config files in project's build output by adding something along these lines to `project.json`:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": {
    "include": ["config.json"]     
  }
}
```

This way, `config.json` will land in the same folder as output binary files. 
Now you can do:

```
env.Initialize(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "UnitTesting");
```

or even better, reference `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` and use:

```
env.Initialize(Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "UnitTesting");
```